# Subtract values in a data frame ignoring specific keys

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames as such:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'pressure' : [42,42,42,42,42,42,42,36,36,36,36,36,36,36], 
                     'load' : [350,350,350,350,350,350,350,700,700,700,700,700,700,700], 
                     'speed' : [70,60,50,40,30,20,10,70,60,50,40,30,20,10], 
                     'lforce' : [3.6,3.5,3.3,3.2,3.1,3.1,2.9,7.7,7.3,7.0,6.8,6.5,6.4,6.1],
                     'rforce' : [3.4,3.2,3.1,3.0,2.9,2.8,2.7,7.6,7.2,6.9,6.6,6.3,6.2,5.9]
                     }).set_index(['pressure','load','speed'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({ 'pressure' : [47,47,47,47,47,47,47], 
                     'load' : [20,20,20,20,20,20,20], 
                     'speed' : [70,60,50,40,30,20,10], 
                     'lforce' : [2.5,2.1,1.9,1.7,1.5,1.3,1.2],
                     'rforce' : [2.8,2.6,2.4,2.2,2.0,1.8,1.7]
                     }).set_index(['pressure','load','speed'])
```

Formatted:

```
>>> df1
                     lforce  rforce
pressure load speed                
42       350  70        3.6     3.4
              60        3.5     3.2
              50        3.3     3.1
              40        3.2     3.0
              30        3.1     2.9
              20        3.1     2.8
              10        2.9     2.7
36       700  70        7.7     7.6
              60        7.3     7.2
              50        7.0     6.9
              40        6.8     6.6
              30        6.5     6.3
              20        6.4     6.2
              10        6.1     5.9
>>> df2
                     lforce  rforce
pressure load speed                
47       20   70        2.5     2.8
              60        2.1     2.6
              50        1.9     2.4
              40        1.7     2.2
              30        1.5     2.0
              20        1.3     1.8
              10        1.2     1.7
```

I would like to subtract `df2` from `df1` on the `lforce` and `rforce` columns for each `speed` to get the resulting data frame `df3`.

My problem is that I need to ignore the `pressure` and `load` in `df2` during the subtraction, but retain the originals from `df1`.

Desired result:

```
>>> df3
                     lforce  rforce
pressure load speed                
42       350  70        1.1     0.6
              60        1.3     0.6
              50        1.4     0.7
              40        1.5     0.8
              30        1.6     0.9
              20        1.7     1.0
              10        1.7     1.0
36       700  70        5.2     4.8
              60        5.1     4.6
              50        5.1     4.4
              40        5.1     4.4
              30        5.0     4.3
              20        5.0     4.3
              10        4.9     4.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df1.sub(df2.reset_index([0, 1], drop=True), level=2)
```

output:

```
                    lforce  rforce
pressure load speed                
42       350  70        1.1     0.6
              60        1.4     0.6
              50        1.4     0.7
              40        1.5     0.8
              30        1.6     0.9
              20        1.8     1.0
              10        1.7     1.0
36       700  70        5.2     4.8
              60        5.2     4.6
              50        5.1     4.5
              40        5.1     4.4
              30        5.0     4.3
              20        5.1     4.4
              10        4.9     4.2
```

Answer (score 1):

May be somehing like this:

```
>>> df3 = df1.reset_index(level=[0,1])
>>> df4 = df2.reset_index(level=[0,1])
>>> df4['pressure'] = 0
>>> df4['load'] = 0
>>> df3 - df4
       pressure  load  lforce  rforce
speed                                
10           42   350     1.7     1.0
10           36   700     4.9     4.2
20           42   350     1.8     1.0
20           36   700     5.1     4.4
30           42   350     1.6     0.9
30           36   700     5.0     4.3
40           42   350     1.5     0.8
40           36   700     5.1     4.4
50           42   350     1.4     0.7
50           36   700     5.1     4.5
60           42   350     1.4     0.6
60           36   700     5.2     4.6
70           42   350     1.1     0.6
70           36   700     5.2     4.8
```

Now you just have to move `pressure` and `load` back to index

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
d1 = df1.reset_index(['pressure','load'])
d2 = df2.reset_index(['pressure','load'])
r0 = d1.merge(d2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
r1 = r0.set_index(['pressure_x','load_x'], drop=False)
r1['lforce'] = r1.lforce_x - r1.lforce_y
r1['rforce'] = r1.rforce_x - r1.rforce_y
df3 = r1[['lforce','rforce']]
df3
```